# Put image in pdf TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am trying to generate a pdf that shows also the image. So my image is stored in the database and I have a working code that generates the data in my database into a PDF file.

This is the code that views my image from my database to the datatable

```
<td ><img  onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity" src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/'.$report["attachment"].'.png'); ?>"  style="width:100%;max-width:200px;border-radius: 5px" ></td>
```

this is what i did but it only prints the img filename

```
if(isset($_POST["generate_pdf"]))  
 {  


      require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');  
      $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('L', 'mm', 'LETTER', true, 'UTF-8', false);
      $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);  
      $obj_pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
      $obj_pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
      $obj_pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');
      $obj_pdf->SetTitle("Incident Report");  
      $obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
      $obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
      $obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
      $obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
      $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
      $obj_pdf->SetMargins(2, '7', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT, '10');  
      $obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
      $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
       $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
      $obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 5);  
      $obj_pdf->AddPage();  

      date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
      $content = '';  
        $content2 = date("F d, Y h:i:s A",mktime());
      $content .= '
      <h4 align="center">Incident Report</h4> <br /> 

      <table align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">  
           <tr>  

                <th width="8%">School</th>  
                <th width="5%">Grade/Level</th> 
                 <th width="6%">Section</th> 
                <th width="7%">Date and Time</th>  
                <th width="6%">Incident Type</th>  
                <th width="7%">Incident Description</th>
                   <th width="6%">Sender</th>  
                <th width="10%">Person Involved</th>   
                   <th width="14%">Students that tagged safe</th> 
                   <th width="14%">Students that tagged unsafe</th> 
                      <th width="4%">Male Count</th> 
                      <th width="5%">Female Count</th> 
                   <th width="5%">Number of involved people</th>
                  if(isset($_POST["generate_pdf"]))  
 {  


      require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');  
      $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('L', 'mm', 'LETTER', true, 'UTF-8', false);
      $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);  
      $obj_pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
      $obj_pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
      $obj_pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');
      $obj_pdf->SetTitle("Incident Report");  
      $obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
      $obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
      $obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
      $obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
      $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
      $obj_pdf->SetMargins(2, '7', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT, '10');  
      $obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
      $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
       $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
      $obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 5);  
      $obj_pdf->AddPage();  

      date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
      $content = '';  
        $content2 = date("F d, Y h:i:s A",mktime());
      $content .= '
      <h4 align="center">Incident Report</h4> <br /> 

      <table align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">  
           <tr>  

                <th width="8%">School</th>  
                <th width="5%">Grade/Level</th> 
                 <th width="6%">Section</th> 
                <th width="7%">Date and Time</th>  
                <th width="6%">Incident Type</th>  
                <th width="7%">Incident Description</th>
                   <th width="6%">Sender</th>  
                <th width="10%">Person Involved</th>   
                   <th width="14%">Students that tagged safe</th> 
                   <th width="14%">Students that tagged unsafe</th> 
                      <th width="4%">Male Count</th> 
                      <th width="5%">Female Count</th> 
                   <th width="5%">Number of involved people</th>
                  <th width="5%">Attachment</th>
           </tr>';  
      $content .= fetch_data();  
      $content .= '</table>';  


      $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);  
      $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content2);
      $obj_pdf->Output('report.pdf', 'I');  
 }  
 ?>  
           </tr>';  
      $content .= fetch_data();  
      $content .= '</table>';  


      $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);  
      $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content2);
      $obj_pdf->Output('report.pdf', 'I');  
 }  
 ?>
```

Do i need to add another $obj_pdf? and I know the line `<th width="5%">Attachment</th>` only prints the filename. I'm just testing waters

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the `src` attribute in the `<img>` tag by feeding a base64 encoded string of the image to the tag.  Like so:

Just put this script in your pdf html where you want the image to be displayed.

HTML Format:

```
<img class="w3-hover-opacity" style="width:100%;max-width:200px;border-radius: 5px" src="data:image/png;base64,'<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents('uploads/'.$report["attachment"] . '.png')); ?>">
```

Or PHP Concatenated string:

```
echo
'<img class="w3-hover-opacity" style="width:100%;max-width:200px;border-radius: 5px" src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents('uploads/'.$report["attachment"] . '.png')) . '">;
```

For the `file_get_contents()` try:

```
file_get_contents(base_url('uploads/'.$report["attachment"] . '.png'))
```

then wrap that in the `base64_encode()` like:

```
base64_encode(file_get_contents(base_url('uploads/'.$report["attachment"] . '.png')))
```

That should do the trick for you.

Comment: Hi joseph! sorry for the late reply, I tried using the HTML format that you provided, there seems to be an error stating that  "file_get_contents(uploads/.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory" It would seem that it does not get the filename. anyway to solve this one?

Comment: Your error says that the path to your image is incorrect.  Just make sure that you have the correct path to the image in the `file_get_contents()` function and it will work.  You may have to use the `base_url()` function that you have in your original code, or set the full path like `my/path/to/my/image.pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

Showing you code i think it is issue of image path.
Please try with below solution:

```
echo '<img class="w3-hover-opacity" style="width:100%;max-width:200px;border-radius: 5px" src="../uploads/'.$report["attachment"].'.png">';
```

For any other information you can visit this [TCPDF Image Example](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/master/examples/example_009.php)